# Button Hiding in Datatables

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I want to hide groups of columns or select the ones to show or hide using buttons in my datatable. This is my javascript code:

```
$('#doentes').DataTable({
     "ajax" :  "phpcode.php",

     "columns" : [ 
     {
      "data" : "item1"
 }, {
      "data" : "item2"
 }, {
      "data" : "item3" 
 }, {
      "data" : "item4"
 }, {
      "data" : "item5"   
 }],

 "scrollX": true,

 "orderFixed": [[ 1, "asc"],[ 2, "asc"],[ 3, "asc"]]

});
```

I can't get the hiding buttons to work, i've tried some examples without success, like:

```
dom: 'Bfrtip',
        buttons: [
            'colvis'
        ]
```

and

```
dom: 'Bfrtip',
        buttons: [
            {
                extend: 'colvisGroup',
                text: 'Group 1',
                show: [ 1, 2 ],
                hide: [ 3, 4 ]
            },
            {
                extend: 'colvisGroup',
                text: 'Group 2',
                show: [ 3, 4 ],
                hide: [ 1, 2 ]
            },
            {
                extend: 'colvisGroup',
                text: 'Group 3',
                show: ':hidden'
            }
        ]
```

How can I apply this to my code?

Edit:
my includes:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/css/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.css">  
          <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
          <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/js/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.js"></script>
```

No error appear on the console when i try those options, the only difference is that the dropdown with the option to show 10, 25,50 and 100 rows per page dissapear.

Comment: Can you show which librarys you are including and maybe check out if you have any errors on the console?

Comment: I updated the question with that info.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I do not see that you are including the needed library for colvis:

```
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.4.2/js/dataTables.buttons.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.4.2/js/buttons.colVis.min.js"></script>
```

> Please note - this property requires the Buttons extension for DataTables.
>   https://datatables.net/reference/button/colvis

As for:

> the only difference is that the dropdown with the option to show 10, 25,50 and 100 rows per page dissapear.

For this on the `dom` option set it like:

```
dom: 'Blfrtip'
```

Where 'l' is the length dropdown: https://datatables.net/examples/basic_init/dom.html

So as resume here an example (a really basic one):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#example').DataTable({
    dom: 'Blfrtip',
    buttons: [
      'colvis'
    ]
  });
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.4.2/css/buttons.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.4.2/js/dataTables.buttons.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.4.2/js/buttons.colVis.min.js"></script>
<table id="example" class="display" width="100%" cellspacing="0">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Position</th>
      <th>Office</th>
      <th>Age</th>
      <th>Start date</th>
      <th>Salary</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tfoot>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Position</th>
      <th>Office</th>
      <th>Age</th>
      <th>Start date</th>
      <th>Salary</th>
    </tr>
  </tfoot>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
      <td>System Architect</td>
      <td>Edinburgh</td>
      <td>61</td>
      <td>2011/04/25</td>
      <td>$320,800</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Garrett Winters</td>
      <td>Accountant</td>
      <td>Tokyo</td>
      <td>63</td>
      <td>2011/07/25</td>
      <td>$170,750</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Ashton Cox</td>
      <td>Junior Technical Author</td>
      <td>San Francisco</td>
      <td>66</td>
      <td>2009/01/12</td>
      <td>$86,000</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Cedric Kelly</td>
      <td>Senior Javascript Developer</td>
      <td>Edinburgh</td>
      <td>22</td>
      <td>2012/03/29</td>
      <td>$433,060</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Airi Satou</td>
      <td>Accountant</td>
      <td>Tokyo</td>
      <td>33</td>
      <td>2008/11/28</td>
      <td>$162,700</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Brielle Williamson</td>
      <td>Integration Specialist</td>
      <td>New York</td>
      <td>61</td>
      <td>2012/12/02</td>
      <td>$372,000</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Herrod Chandler</td>
      <td>Sales Assistant</td>
      <td>San Francisco</td>
      <td>59</td>
      <td>2012/08/06</td>
      <td>$137,500</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Rhona Davidson</td>
      <td>Integration Specialist</td>
      <td>Tokyo</td>
      <td>55</td>
      <td>2010/10/14</td>
      <td>$327,900</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Colleen Hurst</td>
      <td>Javascript Developer</td>
      <td>San Francisco</td>
      <td>39</td>
      <td>2009/09/15</td>
      <td>$205,500</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Sonya Frost</td>
      <td>Software Engineer</td>
      <td>Edinburgh</td>
      <td>23</td>
      <td>2008/12/13</td>
      <td>$103,600</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Jena Gaines</td>
      <td>Office Manager</td>
      <td>London</td>
      <td>30</td>
      <td>2008/12/19</td>
      <td>$90,560</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Quinn Flynn</td>
      <td>Support Lead</td>
      <td>Edinburgh</td>
      <td>22</td>
      <td>2013/03/03</td>
      <td>$342,000</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, I was indeed missing the libraries.

Comment: Without the `dom` option, I can't see any button I try to include, sadly this option is not mentioned in the `Buttons` extention doc.

Comment: @Ben that's because the default of [`dom`](https://datatables.net/reference/option/dom) is `lfrtip` and buttons is an extra plugin that you add